# What is the maximum number of threads that will be allocated to a spring application?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

I have created a simple spring application that will do login process. It will have multiple hits simultaneously if number of logins are high at a same time. I have a doubt in thread allocation process. Need to know how threads are allocated to a spring application and what is the maximum number of threads that will be allocated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am running my application on kubernetes. Do you have any idea about how threads will be allocated while running app on kube nodes?

Comment: in the link there is an example that you can run on your kube node...